# Is there a way in saga-redux to know when saga has run completion in 'main file(?)' to update dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

- I want to do a kind of endless scroll.
- When I scroll, I make a call to my API with Saga.
- I receive the data in this.props.searchSTT.newWord (which are id + word + timestamp)
- When I receive the data I want to create for each word an html element such as :

```
<a
    key={word.WordUID + '_player'}
    id={word.WordUID + '_player'}
    onClick={() => {
        this.props.setCurrentstart(word.Dts as number);
    }}
>
    {word.Word}
</a>
```

Curently it is working because I have put a manual delay of 5sec.
I don't want a manual delay because if my API need 6 sec to return the information it crash.

so my files looks like that :

Result.tsx (where I render the dom)

```js
let c = (
  <div
    id={'myscrolldiv'}
    onScroll={() => {
      let element = document.getElementById('myscrolldiv') as HTMLElement
      if (!isNull(element)) {
        if (element.offsetHeight + element.scrollTop >= element.scrollHeight) {
          if (isNullOrUndefinedOrEmptyArray(this.props.searchSTT.newWords)) {
            this.props.doSearchByDate({
              medias: this.props.searchSTT.currentMediaID,
              start: new Date(previousEnd - offset),
              end: new Date(previousEnd + offset),
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.updateText()
            }, 5000)
          }
        }
      }
    }}
  >
    {this.props.searchSTT.currentSentence}
  </div>
)
```

...

```js
private updateText() {
  let newWords = this.props.searchSTT.newWords
  let sentence = newWords.map(
    (
      word: Proto.media.ISearchSpeechesWord,
      index: number,
      array: Proto.media.ISearchSpeechesWord[]
    ) => {
      return (
        <a
          key={word.WordUID + '_player'}
          id={word.WordUID + '_player'}
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.setCurrentstart(word.Dts as number)
          }}
        >
          {' '}
          {word.Word}{' '}
        </a>
      )
    }
  )
  this.props.setCurrentsentence(sentence)
}
```

my current workarround is to have a fixed delay of 5sec before updating the DOM and hope that during those 5sec I had the answer

From what I understand from the code I working with :
this.props.doSearchByDate() is in action.ts

```js
export const searchSpeechesDate = (
  params: ISearchSTTDateParams
): ISearchSpeechesDateAction =>
  action(SearchSTTActionTypes.SEARCH_SPEECHES_DATE, params)

export const setNewwords = (
  newWords: Proto.media.ISearchSpeechesWord[]
): ISetNewwords => action(SearchSTTActionTypes.SET_NEWWORDS, newWords)

Backend.getInstance().Bind(
  'searchSpeechesDateResult',
  (incoming: IFromCommand) => {
    const cmd = incoming as SearchSpeechesDateResult
    const str = store as Store
    const state = str.getState() as IApplicationState

    try {
      str.dispatch(setNewwords(cmd.results))
    } catch (err) {
      Logger.warn(err as string, 'Unable to parse search words result')
    }
  }
)
```

in saga.ts :

```js
function* handleSearchDate(action: ReturnType<typeof searchSpeechesDate>) {
  const str = store as Store
  const state = str.getState() as IApplicationState
  const cmd = new SearchSpeechDate(
    action.payload.medias,
    action.payload.start,
    action.payload.end
  )
  try {
    yield effects.call(cmd.Send.bind(cmd))
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.warn(err as string, 'Failed to launch search')
  }
}
```

what I would like is instead of having the :
`setTimeout(() => {this.updateText();}, 5000);` I would like to have something like: wait until this.props.searchSTT.newWord is not empty (or an error msg)

I have also tried an infite while checking if this.props.searchSTT.newWord is empty but it is not working either

It has been almost 2 weeks and I couldn't find anything that could help me maybe I don't use the correct term for what I'm looking for, but at this point i'm desesperate

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to update react from sagas is through updating redux store. So the whole process is something like:

1. Dispatch an action from react to get new data  - `doSearchByDate`
2. Listen for the action redux saga, and run some async operation (like fetching stuff from BE) - `*handleSearchDate`
3. Once you have the new data, dispatch them through `put` effect and udpate your redux store state in a reducer - probably whatever `cmd.Send.bind(cmd)` action does
4. react-redux then listens on the store to change and updates your react component with new data (either through `connect` or `useSelector` hook).

This should work for you as well, though the whole `updateText` function feels weird (probably since I lack more context). Usually you wouldn't dispatch JSX through an action, but instead you would just directly rerender your component with new props in render method (or inside function component).

If the whole communication gets more complicated you could also include a callback function in your action (from step 1), and then call it once the saga is done with the new data, though that is kinda an anti-pattern, since redux actions are in essence events and you are not guaranteed by the framework that your action gets handled exactly once (but rather it could be 0-n times). In some situations it is a reasonable workaround though.